# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Сказал я(,) уже сидя за столом".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужна, конечно.
Не обособляются только **одиночные** деепричастия **в наречном значении**. 
Здесь нет ни того, ни  другого.